# Loci in the complex plane

Tags: complex-numbers

Sketch the regions of the complex plane defined by

(a)
$Re
\frac{1 + z}{1 − z}< 0$

and (b)

$Re \space log\frac{1 + z}{1 − z}<0$

for part a i defined z as a + bi and got a final answer of $a^2 + b^2 >1$
Is that right and how to i do part b?

part a)
$\frac{[(1+a) + bi]\cdot[(1-a) +bi]}{[(1-a)-bi]\cdot[(1-a)+bi]}$

=$\frac{1-a^2 - b^2 + 2bi}{(1-a)^2 + b^2}$

now;
$\frac{1-a^2-b^2}{(1-a)^2+b^2} <0$

$1-2\frac{a^2 - a + b^2}{(1-a)^2 + b^2} < 0$

$\frac{1}{2} < \frac{a^2 - a - b^2}{(1-a)^2 = b^2}$

$(1-a)^2 + b^2 < 2a^2 - 2a + 2b^2$

$1 < a^2 + b ^2$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your answer to part (a) is correct, although the solution can be made a little simpler by observing that once you have $$\Re \left(\frac{1+z}{1-z}\right) = \Re \left( \frac{1+2bi-(a^2+b^2)}{(1-a)^2+b^2} \right) = \frac{1-(a^2+b^2)}{(1-a)^2+b^2},$$ and we require this be strictly negative, the denominator, being the sum of real squares, is never negative; thus the given locus reduces to $$1-(a^2+b^2) < 0,$$ which directly results in $a^2 + b^2 > 1$.

For the second part, let $w = (1+z)/(1-z)$.  Then $$\log w = \log |w| + 2\pi i \arg(w) + 2\pi i k, \quad k \in \mathbb Z$$ suggests that the real part is simply the logarithm of the magnitude of $w$.  Since you already calculated $$w = \frac{1+z}{1-z} = \frac{1 + 2bi - (a^2+b^2)}{(1-a)^2+b^2},$$ we have $$|w| = \frac{\sqrt{(1-(a^2+b^2))^2 + (2b)^2}}{(1-a)^2+b^2}.$$  Now simplify this expression and consider when this fraction is less than $1$ (and consequently its logarithm is less than zero).

Comment: Thats what i got for b too, i failed to notice the terms with i will cancel. cheers